# Produce HTML code for tab-delimited text file

Tags: php, html, foreach

I have to perform a task, where I'll be given a tab-delimited text file that will contain some sizechart values and I'll need to produce the HTML table markup for that table.

The text file will have the following format:

```
Adidas men basketball shoes
EU  UK  US  Foot length (1)
18  2   6   22,3 cm.
12  4   27  19,6 cm.
16  7   17  24,8 cm.
14  7.5 8   26,2 cm.
11  9   5   32,6 cm.
24  6   2   19,2 cm.
26  14  4   20,7 cm.
28  8   2   21,7 cm.
```

The first line is the whole chart title, the second contains the column titles, and the third till the end will be the actual size chart values.

The code I produced is the following:

```
<?php
$chart = file_get_contents('test.txt');

foreach (explode("\r\n", $chart) as $row) {
    $ddd[] = explode("\t", $row);
}

//echo '<pre>' . print_r($ddd, true) . '</pre>';

$html = '<style>table { table-layout: fixed; font-size: 14px; text-align: center; }
table thead th, table thead td { padding: 6px; }
table tbody th, table tbody td { padding: 3px; }
table thead { color: #fff; }
table thead tr>* { background: #b42129; }
table thead tr:nth-child(2n)>* { background: #5f5f5f; }
table tbody tr:nth-child(2n)>* { background: #ebebeb; }</style>';

$html .= '<table>';

foreach ($ddd as $k => $row) {
    if ($k === 0) {
        $html .= '<thead><tr><th colspan="' . count($ddd[1]) . '">' . $row[0] . '</th></tr>';
    } elseif ($k === 1) {
        $html .= '<tr>';

        foreach ($row as $ggg) {
            $html .= '<th>' . $ggg . '</th>';
        }

        $html .= '</tr></thead><tbody>';
    } else {
        $html .= '<tr>';

        foreach ($row as $y => $bbb) {
            if ($y === 0) {
                $html .= '<th>' . $bbb . '</th>';
            } else {
                $html .= '<td>' . $bbb . '</td>';
            }
        }

        $html .= '</tr>';
    }
}

$html .= '</tbody></table>';

echo $html;
```

The code works just fine but it looks a bit sloppy. Could someone take a look in case there is something that can be done to tidy it up a little? TIA

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: You think this is sloppy, and it could use some tidying up, why do you think that? What feels wrong or suboptimal about it? If you can't put it into words, just move on. If you can, you should be able to make those changes then. If you are new to this, it really just takes time to find a style that works for you, and even then, sometimes you need to adjust your style when working in different teams or companies.

Comment: @ChrisHaas it feels a bit sloppy, but I'm not new to this. What bothers me mostly (solely actually) is that I can't find some descriptive variable names so I used those `$bbb`, `$ddd` and `$ggg` instead...

Comment: `$ddd` could be `$rows`, `$k` could be `$row_number`, or maybe just `$i`, `$ggg` and `$bbb` are probably `$cell`, and `$y` could be `$cell_number` or just `$j`. That's my guess, but this is a common pattern.